# Ember-Data Embedded Polymorphic BelongsTo not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-app-kit

I've been trying to get polymorphic associations working for me in Ember Data, but I haven't had any luck yet.  Hopefully someone can have a look and let me know if I'm missing something.

I'm using Ember 1.8.1 and Ember-Data 1.0.0-beta.14.1.
Also, we are using the ECMAScript6 syntax (import, export default).

Basically, we just have one embedded polymorphic relationship that doesn't seem to be working for us.  If anyone has any suggestions or ideas about why this isn't working, I'd love some help.  I've been stuck on this one for a few days now.

That's basically what we are having trouble with.  The error that I get returned is:
**Error: Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'metadata' record to this relationship**

```js
// /app/models/metadata.js:
export default DS.Model.extend({
  type: DS.attr('string'),
  lastModified: DS.attr('number');
});

// /app/models/metadata-story.js
import Metadata from '/app/models/metadata';
export default Metadata.extend({
  body: DS.attr('string') 
});

// /app/models/metadata-photo.js
import Metadata from '/app/models/metadata';
export default Metadata.extend({
  url: DS.attr('string'),
  width: DS.attr('number'),
  height: DS.attr('number')
});

// /app/models/post.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  headline: DS.attr('string'),
  metadata: DS.belongsTo('metadata', {polymorphic: true})
});


// /app/serializers/post.js
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
  attrs: {
    metadata: {embedded: 'always'}
  }
});


// /app/routes/posts.js
// Here is the code that is being run to load the records:
export default Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    var query = {
      start: params.start,
      offset: params.offset
    };
    return this.store.find('post', query);
  }
});


// Also, here is a sample of the Payload that the normalizePayload function is returning:
{posts:[
  {
    id: 0,
    headline: 'Well, that is SOME story!',
    metadata: {
      body: 'This is the body...'
    },
    metadataType: 'metadata-story'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    headline: 'Well Hello',
    metadata: {
      url: 'http://somewhere.com/pic.png',
      width: 450,
      height: 350
    },
    metadataType: 'metadata-story'
  }
]}

/* 
Another thing that I should mention is that I have tried setting the Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS flag to both true and false, but it has not seemed to make any difference at this point.
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may be occurring if you are trying to modify a `post` model's `metadata` either by setting it explicitly or via a binding of some sort, and the `set` fails because the value of the `metadata` is not an instance of the ember data's `metadata` model. I would look at all the places in the app where such a modification is being made and console.log the value which is being used to set the `metadata`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not calling "set" anywhere.  This error is occurring in the serializer after a .find() call.